# Lambda expression to get data for a single column where values "In"

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a SQL table "tablex" with 3 columns(A, B ,C ).

The following lambada expression returns 10 rows.

```
var versions = versionRepository.GetVersions(a.id)
```

Column B of the 10 results store data as:  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Can someone help me with the lambda expression to only get results for column C where b in (2,3,4).

So I should only get 3 rows of column C data.

Comment: Are you sure that the column is called  `A.id` with a dot in it? If so, that's a very confusing name.

Comment: It's *really* not clear what you mean - in particular things like "results for column C where b in 2, 3, 4". Are you interested in column B or column C? You filter by whole rows, not columns. Sample data and expected input/output would help. Also note that it's a lambda expression, not lambada.

Comment: A lambada expression is what you would use in the little known Visual Studio Dance Dance version.  You might be able to find it at your local coin arcade....

Comment: The lambada is the dance you do when you get a lambda expression right ;-) There's a little introduction here which explains where the term came from and how it became related to programming - https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:3wkVb1nOqKQJ:www.cs.wright.edu/~tkprasad/courses/cs776/L19Lambda.ppt+history+of+lambda+calculus&hl=en&gl=uk&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEEShWlntC1NgQg4iVejw8FRGppe6V2X5eMOtDKxCchJAkj78rgn2RnI4OkxlK4Ed4jgpAkHQBCogxwqFdMZiqYupGcS6IO8jtz0YtEUjisN-Mxywvy-3jyQOeJZDQ5bN4tnMLok3_&sig=AHIEtbQwq82EvLFLycpzHsNmfC8TjN1lMQ

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `Where` extension method to filter the data, and the `Select` extension method to get only the `C` property:

```
var versions =
  versionRepository.GetVersions(a.id)
  .Where(v => v.B >= 2 && v.B <= 4)
  .Select(v => v.C);
```

(The part `v => v.C` is an example of a lambda expression.)

Comment: Thank you. I just realized I also need 10 from the column b. How could I modify the above to also select where b = 10. Or what I am asking how would I select the values from column B in (2,3,4,10)

Comment: @user1204195: Just add it to the condition: `.Where(v => (v.B >= 2 && v.B <= 4) || v.B == 10)`.

Comment: @user1204195: Have you included the `Select` call?

Comment: Yes I have included the select call.

Comment: @user1204195: If you have, then the result only contains the values from the `C` property.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Contains` to check if it matches one of the numbers you are looking for:

```
List<int> ids = new List<int> { 2, 3, 4, 10 };

var versions =
  versionRepository.GetVersions(a.id)
  .Where(v => ids.Contains(v.B))
  .Select(v => v.C);
```

The trick here is to reverse it around, instead of checking if B is one of the desired numbers, just check if the list of numbers contains B.